# How do I get a Twitter summary card to NOT display any image or default image?

Tags: twitter

When you create a twitter summary card, you can add a meta tag for an image. If you don't add a meta tag for an image, a grey picture of a document appears where the image would have been. This picture takes up nearly a third of the card. I do not want to show any image (not my own and not this default image). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Twitter cards only support Summary (with small image), Summary with large image, Player and App card formats.